# Xcode -Set UIIMageView equal width-height with UITableViewCell

Tags: xcode, uitableview, constraints

I am building my custom cell and I want an ImageView to be equal with the Cell size(constraints for Height,Width) but I noticed that there is not option for that like other views(eg UIView). Am I missing something here or is there any workaround?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Add constraints to center the Image View Horizontaly/Vertical and for Bottom/Top space.